# How to log out a user using the Google User Service API?

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication

I have used the sample code from the google developers page to use google login to authenticate my users.

```
UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
    User user = userService.getCurrentUser();

    if (user != null) {
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().println("Hello, " + user.getNickname());
    } else {
        resp.sendRedirect(userService.createLoginURL(req.getRequestURI()));
    }
```

The first time, I have been redirected to a login page. But after that I am always able to access the following page without logging in. Does anyone know how to unlog a user using the google user service API ?

Answer (score 0):

You cant log out a user. Only the user can log out of their google account.
Probably the user is already logged in by entering another google page before like gmail.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I was looking for the following few lines of code:

```
resp.getWriter().println(
            "<a href='"
                + userService.createLogoutURL(req.getRequestURI())
                + "'> LogOut </a>");
```